# Raspberry Pi UART not working

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart

I've tried everything. Raspberry Pi 4 echo works. Linux echo works. But when I connect the two UARTs together, no information is sent.

Answer (score 1):

Rx should be connected to Tx, not Rx:

```
RPi:    Rx Tx
         | |
         \ /
          x
         / \
         | |
Laptop: Rx Tx
```